# Using proxy with ionic live reload

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to use a certain proxy while developing an ionic app on the mobile device using live reload (i.e., `ionic run android -l`).

I want to keep the ionic live-reload port on 8100 but force the webview URL to use 3000.

So...

Where in the ionic CLI code is the webview URL address+port set when running `ionic run android -l`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the following cheap workaround which has turned out to be a great workflow:

1. specify port 3000 with the ionic CLI: `ionic run android -l --port=3000`   Now you have a built app that uses port 3000.
2. Close the ionic server from your dev machine.
3. Run `ionic serve` and start your proxy server which is wrapping 8100 to 3000.
4. Restart your generated ionic app and it will be using the proxy server.   BINGO!

Now the next time you go to work on the same app, you can skip steps #1 and #2 and just launch your previously-generated app after firing up `ionic serve` and the proxy.

Of course, you will have to rebuild the app if you modify any plugins or config.xml.